# Log only the request names and their status in gatling using logback

Tags: logback, gatling, scala-gatling

Is there any way to log just the request names and their status to a file. The options included in logback are only for logging all requests/responses using TRACE, or for logging only failed requests using DEBUG.

Or is there any way to log the Requests section of the console output using logback? The one which shows the request names and their status (OK/KO)?